# Template literal throwing an Uncaught Syntax error on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the latest Chrome browser, however this piece of code is not working:

```
   const doNum = this.host.startsWith('anything') ? '1938':'200'
   search.append('BX.ref_id', `AMX-DO-${doNum}`)
```

The console shows an error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identified**

I guess it's due to the template literal (`AMX-DO-${doNum}`) used.

What I can use instead to make it work?

Comment: Needs a bit more info, ie what's `search`.  The literal itself, taken to the basics, obviously works fine `var num = 200; var s = \`AMX-DO-${num}\`; console.log(s)`.  You could do `var amx = \`AMX-DO-${doNum}\`; search.append("BX.ref_id", amx);` to eliminate/confirm that it's the literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the old way of [concatenating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Concatenating_strings) the `string` instead of using new `Template literals`

**Use this code** (Should work fine)

```
const doNum = this.host.startsWith('anything') ? '1938' : '200'
search.append('BX.ref_id', 'AMX-DO-' + doNum + '') //concatenate using + sign
```